# MPI_Probe Using MPI_ANY_TAG, Always Returns status.MPI_TAG = 0

Tags: mpi

I am trying to create a message handler that blocking-probes for a message with any tag:

```
MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &probe_status);
```

And then act accordingly depending on the tag:

```
int tag = probe_status.MPI_TAG;
if (tag == 0){
    // The message is of type a
}
else if (tag == 1){
    // The message is of type b
}
```

However, `probe_status.MPI_TAG` is always evaluating to 0, even though I've isolated the senders and only have a single `MPI_Isend` using tag 1.

EDIT:
In fact, even

```
MPI_Probe(0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &probe_status);

cout << rank << ": a message has been found with the probe, with tag " 
     << probe_status.MPI_TAG << ", source " << probe_status.MPI_SOURCE << " 
     and size " << probe_status.count << endl;
```

Gives: Tag 0, source 12 and size 0. There are only 2 nodes running and the probe blocks if the sender is removed so it is finding the 'correct' message being sent from node 0.

EDIT2:
The sender is this:

```
unsigned int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
unsigned int nodes = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();

for(unsigned int i=0; i<nodes; i++){
// Send the release to all nodes except the current
    if(i != rank){
        int taskid[5];
        convert_task_to_id(task_name,taskid);

    Message* message = get_available_message();
    memcpy(message->taskobject_id,taskid, sizeof(taskid));

    message->available = false;
    MPI_Isend(&(message->taskobject_id), 3, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(message->request));
}
}
```

Where `Message` is a `struct` holding `MPI_Request` and a `bool` available (so that I can re-use `MPI_Request`s as they are finished with). In this example, only node 0 sends, and only node 1 will find a message. Using MPICH 3.0.4.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would appear that you're using MPI_PROBE correctly based on your snippet. Can you post the shortest possible version of the code that reproduces the error?

Also, which version of MPI are you using?

Comment: You can't retrieve the count from the status that way. You need to use the MPI function MPI_GET_COUNT.

Comment: MPI_GET_COUNT is retrieving the expected count, thanks. However source and tag are still a weird problem. I'll post the sending-snippet in the main question.

Comment: The idea of what you are doing is correct, but clearly there's a bug in the program somewhere. I think in order to solve this problem, we'll have to see actual, fully compiling code. You're welcome to post it, but you can't just copy/paste your entire application here. You have to be able to trim it down to the smallest possible chunk of code that we can look at (<50 lines).